# XmlException: expected ';' (3B) but found '/' (2F) unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this error message when start a new project in Unity. Reinstall Unity doesn't work. And, don't know if that relevant but VS2017 doesn't see Unity also.

```
XmlException: expected ';' (3B) but found '/' (2F)  Line 58, position 39.
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Expect (Int32 expected)

Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadEntityReference (Boolean ignoreEntityReferences)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadReference (Boolean ignoreEntityReferences)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadText (Boolean notWhitespace)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read ()
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read ()
Mono.Xml.XmlFilterReader.Read ()
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
```

Comment: inspect the `XmlReader r` that is mentioned in the stacktrace, dig out which file it refers to, or whatever textual contents it is reading, then analyze it and/or paste here what you found (path, contents, etc). Otherwise, that's pretty much just guessing or reinstalling everything until it works..

Comment: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/VisualStudioIntegration/SolutionSynchronizer.cs:320) path in text but I cant see this make out what is this. And where XmlReader r might be?

Comment: Did you see this error after upgrading VS 2017 (what version do you use)?

Comment: No, I used VS2017 before. But I reinstall both Unity and VS today. Doesn't help much.

Comment: Do you have an `&` in either your Windows username or Unity project path? See [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/generate-vcproj-failed-xmlexception.530084/)

Comment: I have an ampersand in my Windows username, which also means its in the Unity project path. I had this issue in my Visual Studio assembly file, where I fixed it by replacing the literal "&" with "amp;". Is there a way I could do this for the Unity project files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you have a `&` character in your username or folder structure containing your project.  Use a different user, and/or rename the offending folder.

Comment: Thank you TheSoftwareJedi and FlashOver, I renamed my user folder and took off the ampersand and it eliminated the exception!